# SSRS 2008 Chart and conditional data labels

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, bar-chart

I have a SSRS 2008 stacked bar chart and, as you can see from the screenshot, the series labels are not readable when the data point is small.

My question is can you dynamically show \ hide individual labels within a series if the value is below a certain range?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't **hide** the labels based on individual criteria but you could choose to display **Nothing** instead of a value for each **label**.

In the Series Properties' **Label** property, use and expression like:

```
=IIF(Fields!YourField.Value < 10, NOTHING, Fields!YourField.Value)
```

Comment: Did you try to stick with a 2D chart? There's no gain, just troubles, in adding the third dimension to 2D charts. At least that's what the visualisation experts agree upon.